# Moq - Object type casting and comparison

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to use an IHTMLSelectElement with Moq. My code is something like:

```
// create a select element
var selectElem = new Mock<IHTMLSelectElement>(MockBehavior.Strict);
// set the select element
selectElem.Setup(f => f.length).Returns(20);
selectElem.Setup(f => f.name).Returns("selectElem");            
// get the object
IHTMLSelectElement ihse = selectElem.Object;
```

Then in my production code method, I do:

```
var selectEle = (element as mshtml.IHTMLSelectElement);
if (selectEle != null)
{
```

My problem is that the type cast doesn't work because when using Moq the type is actually:
Castle.Proxies.IHTMLSelectElementProxy_1

Casting this to IHTMLSelectElement returns a null object.

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Comment: Your code definitely should work, because mocked object IS of your interface type.

Comment: But `IHTMLSelectElementProxy_1` inherits from `IHTMLSelectElementProxy`, right? You can do `IHTMLSelectElement ihse = selectElem.Object;`. That makes me think the cast is not your problem.

Comment: Can you show the code where the `ihse` mock is injected into your production class?

Comment: Wow. Turns out it was because in my test I was accidentally using IfacesEnumsStructs.IHTMLSelectElement (from csExWb project) and in my production code i was using mshtml.IHTMLSelectElement.

Thanks for helping me spot this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make it injectable, either a property or a input parameter to a method, depending on the code. And then you can inject the with the MOQ object. The two lines of your code should not be doing the `"as"`, it should be dealing with the correct type of element directly.